# jMonkey SimpleApplication settings

Tags: java, jruby, jmonkeyengine

I'm translating the jMonkey tutorials to JRuby, and currently on the [8th](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3abeginner%3ahello_picking) beginner. But when I run it, it keeps complaining about how there is no `settings` method or local variable defined. Is `settings` supposed to be an instance variable, method, or what?

EDIT: I looked at the javadoc for both `com.jme3.app.Application` *and* `com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication` and neither of them actually define `settings`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mind sharing a link when it's done? Sounds interesting...

Comment: Do you mean a link to a translation of this in JRuby? If so, sure, I can post it on GitHub or something. :)

Comment: Yes, the tutorials, code, etc. I'm planning on learning Ruby soon, and I'd love to see it.

Comment: Hmm... I just realized that I deleted all the tutorials from my computer... :( But I can dig up some other things for you :)

Comment: First of all, [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/video-game-ruby-tutorial-5726.html)'s a really good tutorial that shows you how to use Java's [Slick2D](slick.cokeandcode.com) library to build a simple pong game. I also found [this](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby) wiki article pretty helpful for actually calling Java.

Comment: You could also read some of my other questions relating to JMonkey. They might help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not `settings` method defined anywhere, so I just created my own AppSettings object and used it for the SimpleApplication. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for other people who might get to this question.*

As for newest version of jmonkey, settings are defined in Application.java line 78

```
protected AppSettings settings;
```